# Cannot attach Dropzone to AJAX loaded DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I use Dropzone to handle client side image uploads. The following is a very basic example I have working:
http://www.dressorganic.co.uk/dropzone-test/noajax.htm

As you can see when you view source, I use JQuery to attach Dropzone to the upload1 div ID.

However in the following example I load the upload1 div using AJAX:
http://www.dressorganic.co.uk/dropzone-test/withajax.htm

Unfortunately I cannot get Dropzone to attach to the DIV. I am aware I can insert the JQuery within singleproductupload.asp which contains the HTML to be loaded. But I would prefer to have the JQuery in the parent page.

Here is the main HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dropzone with AJAX</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/dropzone-test/dropzone/4.0.1/dist/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dropzone-test/dropzone/4.0.1/dist/min/dropzone.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {

$("#upload1").dropzone({url: "/dropzone-test/handleupload.asp"});

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/dropzone-test/singleproductload.asp",
  data: { ID: '1' },
  success: function(result) {
    $("#singleproductload").append(result);

  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
  },

  async:true
});     


});  // JQuery
//]]>
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="singleproductload">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the HTML page loaded in AJAX:

```
<div id="upload1" class="dropzone">

   <p>File uploader</p>

</div>
```

Comment: add sources to fiddle please

Comment: I have added the source code to the main question. Unfortunately I could not get this to work on JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I have now fixed the problem here:
http://www.dressorganic.co.uk/dropzone-test/withajax-solution.htm

I had to change the AJAX code to declare Dropzone on the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/dropzone-test/singleproductload.asp",
  data: { ID: '1' },
  success: function(result) {
    $("#singleproductload").append(result);
    $("#upload1").dropzone({url: "/dropzone-test/handleupload.asp"});
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
  },

  async:true
});
```